# calling webservices using Jquery in HTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am learning using web services `[http://88.80.223.163:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/lookup/CommunicationType][1]`

It gives me an XML file..now i want to have the values in a `dropdown list`. How do i call the webservice using `jQuery in HTML` and show the data in a dropdown list??

Comment: How do you  call the webservice?

Comment: i have just started learning today...i have no idea how to do that...kindly help me.

Comment: This will help you ..http://graphnickdesign.com/blog/generating-dynamic-selection-dropdown-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use JQuery to call your webservice and get the xml see this blog post: http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

But if your planning on updating the DOM from a service, I personally think it's easier with [KnockOutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) - I suggest you have a read of the docs and samples.